# Hashing an exe file

Tags: python-3.x, hash, hashlib

How can I *hash* an **executable** file in PYTHON?
I've downloaded an exe file and I have its hash. I want to hash by myself and compare 2 hashes for more certainty.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.md5(open('filename.exe','rb').read()).hexdigest()
```